# Received IP packet header is different from wireshark

Tags: c, network-programming, ip, ping, icmp

I'm trying to recode ping command in C as educational purpose.
The ICMP sending seems OK (I compared it to original ping on wireshark) but on IP packet reception I have the following problem:

The 16 bits of total length in IP header are different from what I see on wireshark.
I use **recvmsg()** function to receive data in a buffer as below.

**UPDATE: I do have this behavior on macos but not on a linux VM**

```
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec iov[1];
    char databuf[1000];
    char datacontrol[1000];

    bzero(&(msg), sizeof(msg));
    bzero(&(iov), sizeof(iov));
    bzero(&(databuf), sizeof(databuf));
    bzero(&(datacontrol), sizeof(datacontrol));


    msg.msg_name = env->addr->ai_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen = env->addr->ai_addrlen;
    iov[0].iov_base = &(databuf[0]);
    iov[0].iov_len = sizeof(databuf);
    msg.msg_iov = iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_control = &(datacontrol[0]);
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(datacontrol);
    msg.msg_flags = 0;

    int retrecv = recvmsg(env.sockfd, &(msg), MSG_WAITALL);
```

When I display the data I receive in **databuf** as below:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--)
            printf("%d", ((databuf[i] >> j) & 1));
        printf("  ");
        if (i == 7 || i == 15)
            printf("\n");
    }
```

I have this as result:

```
01000101  00000000  01000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000
01110100  00000001  11010111  00110011  11011000  00111010  11010101  01001110  
11000000  10101000  00000001  01000100
```

when currently on wireshark I have:

```
01000101  00000000  00000000  01010100  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000
01110100  00000001  11010111  00110011  11011000  00111010  11010101  01001110  
11000000  10101000  00000001  01000100
```

All bits are same except the 3th and 4th (total length of IP packet). I'm aware of little/big endian issue but I don't understand the difference there.

Thank you !

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but semantically your usage of the address-of operator `&` for arrays is incorrect. You should pass a pointer to the first element, not a pointer to the array. For example, plain `databuf` by itself will *decay* to a pointer to its first element, i.e. `&databuf[0]`, which have the type `char *`. When you use `&databuf` you get a pointer to the array itself, which have the type `char (*)[1000]`. Yo're lucky that both are pointing to the same location, but as I said they're semantically different due to the difference in type.

Comment: True! I didn't notice but I changed it. Thank you!